# AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010

I was creating a new sharepoint webpart in VS2010. After publishing the webpart and trying to access it. i was getting following error.
That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.
after adding the following assembly level attribute the issue is rectified.
 [assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()] 
I coudn't get the significance of the attribute. Can anyone explain about the attribute.

Comment: There are a lot of Q&As asking the cause of this and how to solve it on a surface level, it is great to see a Q looking for the actual details behind it which is what I was hoping for. Keep it up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET framework prevents assemblies running in partial trust to call assemblies with full trust in order to prevent luring attacks. The AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers attribute indicates that you wish to override this security check for the given assembly.

A more detailed description can be found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/02/04/367390.aspx